# Correlation Differences in R

Tags: r, regression, correlation

Something mesmerizes me in R:

1. Why are they differences in my correlations depending on the
   function/package I use and
2. Which package::function should I choose in what circumstances

Consider the three following examples using the [Iris Dataset](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/iris):

**stats::cor.test**

```
cor.test(iris$petal.length, iris$petal.width, method='pearson')
#t = 43.32, df = 148, p-value < 2.2e-16
#cor = 0.9627571
```

**stats::lm**

```
summary(lm(iris$petal.length ~ iris$petal.width))
#(Intercept)       1.09057    0.07294   14.95   <2e-16 ***
#iris$petal.width  2.22589    0.05138   43.32   <2e-16 ***
#Multiple R-squared:  0.9269,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.9264 
#F-statistic:  1877 on 1 and 148 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

**[lsr::correlate](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lsr/versions/0.5/topics/correlate)**

```
correlate(iris$petal.length, iris$petal.width, test=TRUE)
# Correlation
#      y.var   
#x.var 0.963***
#p-value
#       y.var
# x.var 0.000
```

They all give similar values. For instance, the p-value in this example is always the same. The R is also really close ranging from 0.9264 to 0.963 and is in fact identical for `stats::cor.test` and `lsr::correlate`.

Comment: stats::lm is not giving you the correlation coefficient. It's giving you the R^2. The correlation values from lsr::correlate and stats::cor.test are 
about 0.9627. Square that and you get 0.9627^2 = 0.9267, which is almost identical to the R^2 value from stats::lm. I expect any differences there are due to rounding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turning my comment above into an answer:

`stats::lm` is NOT giving you the correlation coefficient (i.e. *r*). It's giving you the R<sup>2</sup>.

The correlation values from `lsr::correlate` and `stats::cor.test` are about 0.9627. Square that and you get 0.9627<sup>2</sup> = 0.9268, which is almost identical to the R<sup>2</sup> value from `stats::lm`. The small differences there are almost certaintly due to rounding.